# Batch command/script to do commands from .txt file?

Tags: windows, batch, script

Im trying to find a command or a script that can do commands from a specified .txt file. e.g it would treat a .txt file as a batch file but not necessarily rename it to .bat.

Can anyone help?

e.g:

```
cmd "filename.txt"
do cmd
```

That would run filename.txt as a .bat file and do any commands in it.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Im looking for it to execute Line-By-Line as an individual command. Is there some sort of .exe utility for it?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Is it a EXE utility?

Comment: Okay, I just added another batch script solution as a separate answer that will process each line from the text command file one by one. I tested it extensively and this is the best way I was able to get the logic to work as expected so that should do what you ask so try it out; no need for an executable to do this from what I tested.

Comment: there are quite a lot of duplicates on SO: [Running a non bat extension file as a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21242301/995714), [How to DIRECTLY execute command in txt file in cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21657655/995714), [Windows batch file that reads commands from txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1658441/995714), [how do i get a batch file to accept input from a txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10653371/995714), [Execute Commands from Any Text File (Not Having “.bat” or “.cmd” Extensions)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23162474/995714)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### I'm trying to find a command or a script that can run commands from a .txt file

The simplest solutions are always the best.

Use the following command:

> cmd < command.txt

Or:

> type command.txt|cmd

Source StackOverflow answer [How to DIRECTLY execute command in txt file in cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21657757/3536342) by [MC ND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd) and it's comments.

Note:

> There are several commands that will not work in this file, like `goto`, `setlocal` and others. However, multi-line nested `if` and `for` commands do work as long as for replaceable parameters use just one percent (like in the command-line).

Source StackOverflow answer [Running a non bat extension file as a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242301/running-a-non-bat-extension-file-as-a-batch-file) by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)

See StackOverflow answer [How to run batch script without using *.bat extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320578/how-to-run-batch-script-without-using-bat-extension), also by by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini), for more observations on this approach. This answer also includes a link to code that can get `goto` and `call` working as well!

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Answer (score 7):

### Run a Text File as a Batch Script

Yes this is possible by making the text file which contains the commands you need executed to be referenced as the first [batch argument](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) that is passed to the batch script.

You can set the argument value as a variable and using [type](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html) you can create a temporary batch file with the content of the text file and then run that file through [cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to process accordingly.

---

### Batch Script Logic

```
@ECHO ON

SET cmdtxt=%~1
SET cName=%~N1

if exist "%tmp%\%cName%.cmd" del /q /f "%tmp%\%cName%.cmd"
if not exist "%tmp%\%cName%.cmd" type "%cmdtxt%" >> "%tmp%\%cName%.cmd"
cmd /k "%tmp%\%cName%.cmd"

pause
exit
```

> **Note:** *You can use [cmd /c](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to have the command window(s) close after execution.*

---

### Text File

```
ECHO Line 1
dir *.txt
```

> **Note:** *This is the text file without a `.bat` or `.cmd` which each line will contain a valid batch command which will be executed.*

---

### Execute this by using either. . .

> ### 1.Drag and Drop
>
> > [image] 
> >     [image]
>
> ---
>
> ### 2. Command Line
>
> ```
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\RunMe\RunTextCommands.cmd "C:\Users\User\Desktop\RunMe\cmd.txt"
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### `@ECHO OFF` Results
>
> [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

  > %* in a batch script refers to all the arguments (e.g. %1 %2 %3 %4
  >   %5 ...%255)  only arguments %1 to %9 can be referenced by number.
- [If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [Type](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html)
- [Cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)
- `FOR /?`

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > ```

Answer (score 2):

### Run Individual Lines from a Text File as Batch Commands

Yes this is possible by making the text file which contains the commands you need executed to be referenced as the first [batch argument](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) that is passed to the batch script.

You can then run the file through a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop and iterate over the content of each line individually and pass each [command] value to [`cmd /c`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to execute accordingly.

---

### Batch Script Logic

```
@ECHO ON

SET cmdtxt=%~1

FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=*" %%A IN ("%cmdtxt%") do (
    cmd /c "%%~A"
    )
::PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Text File

```
ECHO Line 1
dir *.txt
```

> **Note:** *This is the text file without a `.bat` or `.cmd` which each line will contain a valid batch command which will be executed.*

---

### Execute this by using either. . .

> ### 1.Drag and Drop
>
> > [image] 
> >     [image]
>
> ---
>
> ### 2. Command Line
>
> ```
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\RunMe\RunTextCommands.cmd "C:\Users\User\Desktop\RunMe\cmd.txt"
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ### `@ECHO OFF` Results
>
> [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [Cmd](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

Comment: Hmm. This will only work with a very simplified subset of commands. For example, any command that is over multiple lines, or requires interpretation by a cmd shell, will not work.

Comment: Yes, the OP should test the commands that are on each line as requested to iterate and run separately and individually for the needs as setup in the environment, etc.